# Collaboration-Information on Word for strangers

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

can I see as a stranger in a Word-document, if a document was worked in collaboration by multiple people?
And if so, can I see the changes each person made?
Could an RTF-Format give me additional informations on those regarding questions?

Best regards

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Version history would only come if the document is on SharePoint or some other CMS-type platform. The document itself will only show authors and editors, but not what they changed. RTF will likely lose that information too, as it's purely Rich Text.

Answer (score 0):

**RTF will contain *less* information.**

### If you have Track Changes turned on and locked you should be able to see every edit and the source.

Of course, if you have that, other editors will also have access to the information.

Here is my chapter on [Track Changes](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/track_changes.htm).

Someone sufficiently skilled and devious likely can work around this, though.